# Hibernate OneToMany. Getting empty list when loadin from DB

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-many

I'm new to Hibernate so my question can be silly a bit, by i'm stucked and will be glad to  get help.

I have two entities: Book and Tag with following structure:

```
@Entity
public class BookEntity{

@Column(nullable = false)
private String title;
@Column(nullable = false)
private String author;
private String publisher;
private int edition;
private int yearOfPublishing;

@Id
@Column(name = "isbn")
private String isbn;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "isbn") },
           inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "tagId") })
private List<Tag> tags;
//getters & setters
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Tag implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int tagId;
private String tagValue;
//getters & setters
```

Insertion works fine, here is the HQL queries:

```
insert into PUBLIC.BookEntity 
(author, edition, publisher, title, yearOfPublishing, isbn) 
values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

insert into PUBLIC.Tag
(tagId, tagValue) 
values (null, ?)
```

Selection queries looks fine also:

```
select
        bookentity0_.isbn as isbn35_1_,
        bookentity0_.author as author35_1_,
        bookentity0_.edition as edition35_1_,
        bookentity0_.publisher as publisher35_1_,
        bookentity0_.title as title35_1_,
        bookentity0_.yearOfPublishing as yearOfPu6_35_1_,
        tags1_.isbn as isbn35_3_,
        tag2_.tagId as tagId3_,
        tag2_.tagId as tagId36_0_,
        tag2_.tagValue as tagValue36_0_ 
    from
        PUBLIC.BookEntity bookentity0_ 
    left outer join
        PUBLIC.BookEntity_Tag tags1_ 
            on bookentity0_.isbn=tags1_.isbn 
    left outer join
        PUBLIC.Tag tag2_ 
            on tags1_.tagId=tag2_.tagId 
    where
        bookentity0_.isbn=?
```

But when i'm loading BookEntity from database i'm getting correct object with empty list of Tags.
The loading object from database :

```
public T read(PK id) {
    LOG.debug("Reading by id={}", id.toString());
    return (T)getSession().get(type, id);
}
```

where T is BookEntity, type is Class and PK is String.

What am i doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the insert into the `BookEntity_Tag` join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all choosing isbn as a primary key is not the most inspired idea. What if the user makes a typo and enters a wrong isbn?

Secondly, it seems to me that you are trying to map a many to many relation from books to tags. Or maybe a one to many?

For many to many use:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "book_tag",
   joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "isbn")},
   inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")}
)
```

For one to many use:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "isbn", nullable = false)
```

But you better replace isbn with a book_id.

Comment: Thanks, that works! About isbn - client code will create Books only through Builder which validates isbn code, so it wont let user to persist wrong data. When isbn is pk it is easier to kepp data integrity.